# Can't disable debugfs with AppArmor

Tags: containers, apparmor

I need to disable `debugfs` with AppArmor on my **privileged** container.
Inside the container anyone can just run `debugfs /dev/sda1` and see all the host files.
When I searched how to do it, I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/848237/780516) link which wrote that I just need to run:

```
umount debugfs
```

Unfortunately, I still can use `debugfs`.
I don't want to delete `debugfs` because it easy to bring this file.
I tried also:

```
mv /lib/systemd/system/sys-kernel-debug.mount/lib/systemd/system/sys-kernel-debug.mount.disabled
```

But I am still able to run `debugfs /dev/sda1`.

I want to block it with AppArmor, so I used the `deny mount fstype=debugfs` and `deny /sys/kernel/debug/* mrwklx` but it doesn't block it.
My AppArmor file:

```
#include <tunables/global>


profile docker-profile flags=(attach_disconnected,mediate_deleted) {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  network,
  capability,
  file,
  umount,
  ptrace,
  mount,
  pivot_root,

  deny mount fstype=debugfs,
  deny /sys/kernel/debug/* mrwklx, 
}
```